# Update row in data extension with SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, c#

I'm having trouble updating a row in data extension. Code I use:

```
int businessUnitID; //Unit ID
string dataExtensionCustomerKey; //Data Extension Customer Key
DataExtensionObject row; //Data Extension row I want to update, retrieved with previous call and with Properties changed
APIProperty[] PrimaryKeys; //Data Extension Primary Keys

row.Keys = PrimaryKeys;
row.CustomerKey = dataExtensionCustomerKey;

UpdateOptions uo = new UpdateOptions();
SaveOption so = new SaveOption();
so.PropertyName = "*";
so.SaveAction = SaveAction.UpdateOnly;

uo.SaveOptions = new SaveOption[] { so };

ClientID client = new ClientID();
client.ID = businessUnitID;
client.IDSpecified = true;
client.ClientID1 = businessUnitID;
client.ClientID1Specified = true;

uo.Client = client;

UpdateResult[] uResults;
String uStatus;
String uRequestID;

uResults = ETSoapClient.Update(uo, new APIObject[] { row }, out uRequestID, out uStatus);

return uResults;
```

Error Message I get: 
Exception occurred during [Update:ProcessUpdateBatch] ErrorID: xxx

Comment: Where are you setting `dataExtensionCustomerKey` and `PrimaryKeys`?  Seems like that would be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. DataExtensionObject represents DataExtension Object not a record row. The Keys attribute requires you to pass Key Name and Value for that record
2. To update an row, you need to use DataExtensionObject.Properties and pass a collection of APIProperty with column Name and Value.

For example you want to update David's firstname and lastname,  with "Email" field as unique key:

```
DataExtensionObject deo = new DataExtensionObject();
deo.CustomerKey = data_extension_customerkey;
deo.Keys = new APIProperty[1];
deo.Keys[0] = new APIProperty();
//Primary Key column
deo.Keys[0].Name = "Email";
deo.Keys[0].Value = "david@example.com";


deo.Properties = new APIProperty[2]; //Two columns to update

deo.Properties[0] = new APIProperty();
deo.Properties[0].Name = "Firstname";
deo.Properties[0].Value = "David";

deo.Properties[1] = new APIProperty();
deo.Properties[1].Name = "Lastname";
deo.Properties[1].Value = "Hughes";
```